Do the findings of this paper make sense?
I have an question about a paper I read recently because I'm not sure if I'm not capable enough to understand the “Findings” part or if the authors did it badly. I'll try to summarize it here, but here is also the link to the paper: An Innovative Approach to Linear Algebra Course: Using Manga Comics by Ayse Arzu Ari; Baris Demir (Shanlax International Journal of Education, v11 spec iss 1 p29-38 2023).
The authors conduct a study with an experimental and a control group of 24 subjects each. They measure an effect before and after an intervention (Achievement and Attitudes in Linear Algebra, more details in the paper if you are interested). Starting on page 34 they describe the findings. There, the comparisons of pre- and post-test within both groups, as well as the comparisons of both measurement times between both groups are presented in tabular form. I now refer further to “Achievement”, which is Tables 1, 3, 4 and 5, but my questions are the same for the “Attitude” data. The authors say that they use a t-test, that Kolmogorov Smirnov (p=.558; p>.05) and Levene (0.003) are ok.
I have summarized the tables in an image (here: https://ibb.co/XFJLPbw).

In the tables, the control and experimental groups are abbreviated as K2 and E2 respectively, with “pre” or “post” for the time of measurement. Below this there are also the things from the body text for the tables that I found important for the context.
My questions about this:

from the data or rather the degrees of freedom given (see image), I understand that a t-test for independent samples was performed for the comparisons of the two groups and one for related samples for the comparison within the groups. However, shouldn't there be 24+24-2=46 degrees of freedom for the former with N=24 in both groups and not 47?

the abbreviations S (probably standard deviation?) and S.S. (sum of squares??) are used in the tables. This does not seem to be the same, because in cells where I would actually expect the same values, there are different ones. Are these common abbreviations? If so, can someone tell me what they mean?

because I was confused and skeptical, I tried to calculate the t-value for the comparison of the pretests of both groups (top left table in the image) by hand (with the values for sample sizes, mean values and the standard deviations of the table). But I get 0.397. What am I doing wrong? I used an equation for homogeneous variance from here: https://datatab.de/assets/tutorial/t-Test-f%C3%BCr-unabh%C3%A4ngige-Stichproben-homogene-Varianz.png


I would be really grateful for any help, as my limited knowledge is getting me absolutely nowhere.

Yes, the d.f is wrong; it should be 46. Which makes the p-value=.693, but the test statistic T=.397! Check this online calculator https://www.statskingdom.com/140MeanT2eq.html Indeed, I am not sure what they mean by t(47)?

Also, K-S test and Levene's test are worthless here.

Thanks for your replies. My guess is that t(47) refers to value of the test statistic with 47 degrees of freedom, since it is always the same value as in the corresponding table. I just don't understand why it would be 0.713 for the upper left table.
Any idea on what the difference is between "S" and "S.S." in the table headers?
